# In $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is it true that $F_{a,b}=\{p\in\mathbb{C}[x] : p(a)=p(b)\}$ for $a\neq b$ is a maximal subring?

Tags: commutative-algebra, polynomials

The problem is in the title. It is clear that $F_{a,b}$ is a ring, but it is not so clear to me that it is maximal in $\mathbb{C}[x]$. I tried to consider it as a vector space and show that it has codim=1 but I didn't go far with that. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The thing you tried is a good idea. You just need to find a linear functional that vanishes precisely on $F_{a, b}$. Does the definition suggest one?

Comment: I completely missed the part where you said that the functional should vanish on $F_{a,b}$. So I should consider the functional $f(p)=p(a)-p(b)$. I think it is correct now.

Comment: Yep. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: OK! I think I understand it now. The idea is that $Imf = \mathbb{C}$. So $\mathrm{codim}kerf=\mathrm{dim}\mathbb{C}[x]/kerf= \mathrm{dim}Imf =1$. I am not very familiar with the concept of codim in infinite dimensional spaces, so if you can find some mistakes I would be grateful if you can correct them.

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly. In the infinite-dimensional setting you can't define codimension by subtraction so you are forced to define it as the dimension of the quotient space.

Comment: OK! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Feel free to write an answer below, by the way.

Comment: I posted the solution. Is it correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is based on the hints and insights of Qiaochu Yuan.

We can consider the rings and subrings as vector spaces. If $T\leq \mathbb{C}[x]$ then $T$ is a subspace of the vector space $\mathbb{C}[x]$. So, in order to prove that $T$ is a maximal subring of $\mathbb{C}[x]$, we can just prove that $\operatorname{codim}T = 1$. Indeed, suppose by contradiction that $\operatorname{codim}T = 1$ and $T$ is not a maximal subring of $\mathbb{C}[x]$. In this case we have that there exists $V$ a subring of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ such that $T\subsetneq V\subsetneq \mathbb{C}[x]$. But in the context of vector spaces, that means that $\operatorname{codim}T> \operatorname{codim}V\geq 1$ which implies that $\operatorname{codim}T>1$. Contradiction! So it is true that $$\operatorname{codim}T = 1 \Rightarrow T \text{ is a maximal subring of } \mathbb{C}[x].$$
In our case we choose the linear functional $f:\mathbb{C}[x]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defined by $f(p)=p(a)-p(b)$. Clearly $F_{a,b} \equiv \ker f$. Furthermore $\operatorname{Im}f=\mathbb{C}$. So
$$\operatorname{codim}\ker f=\dim\mathbb{C}[x]/\ker f=\dim\operatorname{Im}f = \dim\mathbb{C}=1.$$
From what we proved above, since $\operatorname{codim}F_{a,b}=1$ we have that $F_{a,b}$ is a maximal subring of $\mathbb{C}[x].$